# Insert time data into SQL Server with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to know how to insert TIME into SQL Server using C#

I have a class that I use as a data layer:

```
    public class Main_Lom_Form
    {
        public string Specimen_ID
        public int Client_Key
        public string Outcome
        public string Medications
        public DateTime Date_Collected
        public DateTime Time_Collected
```

and I do not know if I should be declaring `Time_Collected` as DateTime?

What type should `Time_Collected` be so that if the time would be `13:05` it would be entered correctly into a column in SQL Server 2008 that is a `TIME(7)` datatype?

Comment: You can use a datetime to store it, you can use `Date_Collected.TimeOfDay.ToString()` and SQL-Server will parse it to the correct TIME(7) datatype. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `TimeSpan` maps to `time(7)`
- `DateTime` maps to `datetime`

If you only want to store time, then `time(7)` should be okay. Is there a reason why you don't combine `Date_Collected` and `Time_Collected` into one field of type `datetime`?

Comment: in that case which datatype on sql server should i choose?

Comment: (Edited my comment into answer above.)